# Angular 2: Can't use array passed from parent within child template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to create a Kanban table using Angular 2. Basically, I have the following component structure within my application:

app

- `app.component.ts`
- `app.component.html`
- `project.class.ts`
- task-assignment

  - `task-assignment.component.ts`
  - `task-assignment.component.html`
  - `task.class.ts`

My `app.component.ts` looks something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectObject } from './project.class';

import { TaskAssignmentComponent } from './task-assignment/task-assignment.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

    title = 'My Project Table';

    // array of tasks
    tasks = [];

    // array of assignable projects (non-dynamic)
    projects = [
        new ProjectObject('1', 'Client Request'),
        new ProjectObject('2', 'UI Admin Panel'),
        new ProjectObject('3', 'Webservice')
    ]

    // some functions here...

}
```

My `app.component.html` includes the task-assignment component to which I'm trying to pass my projects object:

```
<task-assignment [tasks]="tasks" [projects]="projects"></task-assignment>
```

My task-assignment component code looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { TaskObject } from './task.class';

@Component({
    selector: 'task-assignment',
    templateUrl: './task-assignment.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./task-assignment.component.css']
})

export class TaskAssignmentComponent {

    @Input('tasks') tasks: Array<any>;
    @Input('projects') projects: Array<any>;

    // some functions here...

}
```

Within my child component template `task-assignment.component.html` I'm trying to output a list of the Projects object contents like this:

```
<select name="project">
  <option value="" selected="selected">choose project</option>
  <option *ngFor="let project of projects" value="{{project.ID}}">{{ project.name }}</option>
</select>
```

I've already tried to log my projects object to the console using an OnInit function in my `task-assignment.component.ts` - successfully.

However - the corresponding template `task-assignment.component.html` is somehow unable to access the `projects` object. There's no rendering error within the browsers console or Webpack.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? 
Thanks a bunch in advance.

**======= UPDATE =======**

My `project.class.ts` looks like this:

```
export class ProjectObject {
  constructor(
    public ID: string,
    public name: string
  ){}
}
```

Executing a `console.log(this.projects)` within `task-assignment.component.ts` using the `ngOnInit()` method prints out the following:

```
Array[3]
  0: ProjectObject
  ID: "1"
  name: "Client Request"
  __proto__: Object // array with constructor info 'n' stuff inside

  1: ProjectObject
  ID: "2"
  name: "UI Admin Panel"
  __proto__: Object // array with constructor info 'n' stuff inside

  2: ProjectObject
  ID: "3"
  name: "Webservice"
  __proto__: Object

  length: 3
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: try rendering {{ project | json }} inside of your option tag.  Is the JSON data as you would expect? It looks like you have ID and name, I'm wondering if the case is correct

Comment: thanks for the tip - I've tried it out. unfortunately, it won't print out anything. i've updated my post by providing my project.class.ts contents as well as my console.log of the projects object. maybe that helps to bring some light to the problem...

Comment: What happens when you try to console.log the same thing you're trying via string interpolation? Does it work? If not, what errors do you see?

Comment: I tried to replicate this issue in [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xVHA0i0AdO94rps7gs6E?p=preview) and found nothing, it worked, hope this link helps you

Comment: @Muirik it prints out all three objects just as expected when i try it. don't know why the template expression isn't able to access the data...

Comment: @amansinghgusain dafuq... how? :D this is grinding my gears. thank you for the example though. seems i have to hunt down a minor bug...

Comment: So are you getting any errors in this situation? Usually Angular's pretty good about pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @Muirik well... actually before I tried to console.log() the object via ngOnInit() there weren't any errors. When I did, the objects got logged to the console just as expected - but right after this log the console stated an 'undefined' and that there is no length property to an undefined object (i logged the projects objects by iterating through them using a for-loop: for(let i=0;i<this.projects.length;i++) { console.log(this.projects[i]) }). ... i also get the undefined when i try to log the projects in any other function but the ngOnInit(). Resetting it by using a constructor didn't work...

Comment: No such errors in the post as per this Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/tflpjekpkp0FERrAmnhK?p=preview